# What time complexity is a reachability algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory

I've read there are ways you can determine all reachable pairs using Strongly Connected Components. But, I want to calculate all reachable nodes on the fly - so I don't have to store a massive reachability matrix in RAM. What sort of time complexity would be possible for an algorithm to calculate all reachable nodes in a directed graph, from a single node?

[image]

Here's a naive algorithm I came up with, I'm not sure of the time complexity of this. $O(n!)$?

It seems to have an $O(n)$ spacial complexity though.

I've read about the Bellman-Ford algorithm with a time complexity of $O(EV)$ which is essentially $O(V^3)$ and the Floyd-Warshall algorithm which is $O(V^3)$. They require $O(V)$ and $O(V^2)$ space complexity, respectively.

The problem is only inputs can be determined in constant time. So, one would have to find (in $O(n)$ time)  all outputs for a particular neuron. What I actually did in my solution is invert the graph using a similar technique, before running DFS. But I don't know if this is optimal...

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search. Running breadth-first_search from your original node $v_{start}$ you can determine in linear time ($ \mathcal{O}(|V| + |E|)$) all nodes reachable from $v_{start}$.

Comment: @araomis The problem is only inputs can be determined in constant time. So, one would have to find (in $O(n)$ time)  all outputs for a particular neuron. What I actually did in my solution is invert the graph using a similar technique, before running DFS. But I don't know if this is optimal...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "only inputs can be determined in constant time. So, one would have to find (in () time) all outputs for a particular neuron."

Comment: This technique also has a spacial complexity of O(n^2) as I have an inverted copy of the graph in memory

Comment: @araomis The way the graph is implemented is recursively. "incoming edges" are an attribute of every node. So, you can't simply traverse all the outputs, because you don't know where a particular neuron is outputted to - unless you check every other nodes inputs and see if this neuron exists inside

Comment: Ah I understand. And I gather you already have an algorithm which just builds the graph from the information you have and then runs DFS / BFS but you don't like it because there could be O($n^2$) edges, correct?  Notice that your input is of size roughly $n + m$ where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ the number of edges. Thus you should explicitly mention that you want an algorithm linear in $n$ and not only linear in $n + m$.